# dockerd[30551]: Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted

Tags: 16.04, server, mount, docker

when i do `service docker start`
i got `Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details`.

```
    Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.011881198Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.011927591Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.011963577Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.011969872Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.011974323Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.011997968Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.012043218Z" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42016e920, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.012042561Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.012065081Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.012097777Z" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420798450, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.012160188Z" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42016e920, READY" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.012333289Z" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420798450, READY" module=grpc
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.013074262Z" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay suppo
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.013727646Z" level=error msg="AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems" storage-driver=aufs
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.014310074Z" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay suppo
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.014327293Z" level=error msg="Failed to built-in GetDriver graph devicemapper /var/lib/docker"
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.171171176Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.171316041Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support oom control"
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.171326556Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support memory swappiness"
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.171333407Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit"
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.171337732Z" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.171355692Z" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: time="2019-03-25T23:09:38.171381746Z" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
Mar 25 23:09:38 s104-238-125-129.secureserver.net dockerd[30551]: Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted


root@--:~# dockerd --debug
DEBU[2019-03-25T23:16:21.765477846Z] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
DEBU[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766231848Z] Golang's threads limit set to 230040
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766410295Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766419631Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766448342Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766453631Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
DEBU[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766499436Z] Using default logging driver json-file
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766513748Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]  module=grpc
DEBU[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766524287Z] [graphdriver] priority list: [btrfs zfs overlay2 aufs overlay devicemapper vfs]
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766532933Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
DEBU[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766554463Z] zfs command is not available: exec: "zfs": executable file not found in $PATH  storage-driver=zfs
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766570666Z] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420706f80, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766557173Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]  module=grpc
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766585405Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766618436Z] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4208b2120, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766617267Z] blockingPicker: the picked transport is not ready, loop back to repick  module=grpc
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766701406Z] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420706f80, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766735535Z] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4208b2120, READY  module=grpc
DEBU[2019-03-25T23:16:21.766781267Z] processing event stream                       module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
ERRO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.767413837Z] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.  storage-driver=overlay2
ERRO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.768029156Z] AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems       storage-driver=aufs
ERRO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.768588549Z] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.  storage-driver=overlay
ERRO[2019-03-25T23:16:21.768601233Z] Failed to built-in GetDriver graph devicemapper /var/lib/docker
DEBU[2019-03-25T23:16:21.768650566Z] Initialized graph driver vfs
INFO[2019-03-25T23:16:22.339244087Z] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds
WARN[2019-03-25T23:16:22.339384429Z] Your kernel does not support oom control
WARN[2019-03-25T23:16:22.339396795Z] Your kernel does not support memory swappiness
WARN[2019-03-25T23:16:22.339403500Z] Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit
WARN[2019-03-25T23:16:22.339407086Z] Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts
WARN[2019-03-25T23:16:22.339423992Z] Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts
WARN[2019-03-25T23:16:22.339449197Z] mountpoint for pids not found
DEBU[2019-03-25T23:16:22.339610848Z] Cleaning up old mountid : start.
Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  What method did you use to install docker?

Comment: curl https://get.docker.com | sh

Comment: Personally, I would remove the docker you have installed, and the `sudo apt install docker.io` - this brings version 18.09 to Cosmic.  Alternatively, you could run though the error messages to see whats missing.  At least, you will need to install cgroups, which *might* be satisfied by `sudo apt-get install cgroup-bin cgroup-lite libcgroup1`

Comment: i installed the packaged but same problem